# How to create a lap function for a countdown timer in Kivy

Tags: python, timer, kivy, kivy-language

I have a countdown timer that starts at a random integer number within the range given by the randint() arguments and counts down to zero. The aim is to make the timer restart at a new random number the first time it reaches zero (i.e. lap function) and to display "FINISH" the second time it reaches zero.

This is my first time using kivy, so apologies if the solution is obvious. At present I only require two iterations, but I may need to adjust this later so that the timer will lap any number of times before finally stopping. The number of laps will be determined in the code before running the app, and not by the app user whilst running the app.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from random import randint


class IncrediblyCrudeClock(Label):
    for i in range(2):
        r=randint(3,7)
        a = NumericProperty(r)  # Number of seconds to countdown


        def start(self):  #Function to initiate the countdown
            Animation.cancel_all(self)  # stop any current animations
            self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)  #a=0 sets the 
#final destination of a. duration sets the time taken to reach stopping 
#point (i.e 5 seconds for a=5)
            def finish_callback(animation, incr_crude_clock):
                if self.i==1:
                    incr_crude_clock.text = "FINISHED"  #when the clock 
#reaches zero, display "FINISHED"
            self.anim.bind(on_complete=finish_callback)  #call the 
#finish_callback function once a=0
            self.anim.start(self)  #Start the animation (otherwise clock 
#stuck at 5 for a=5)


class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        crudeclock = IncrediblyCrudeClock()
        crudeclock.start()
        return crudeclock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()



<IncrediblyCrudeClock>
    text: str(round(self.a, 1))
```

The app does run as expected for the first countdown. A random number is selected and the timer counts down to zero, but it stops and displays "FINISHED" after the first count down. It seems as though the for loop is iterating from zero to one before the app is actually started, so, by the time the countdown starts, i is already equal to 1 (in stead of running first from a to zero with i=0 and then from new a to zero with i=1). I imagine this is because the for loop is in the wrong place (i.e. not upon calling the start function), but I have been unable to work out how to rectify this.
This is also my first time using stack overflow, so please let me know if you need to know anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that repeats the countdown a specified number of times:

```
from random import randint
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class IncrediblyCrudeClock(Label):
    a = NumericProperty(0)  # Number of seconds to countdown

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.max_laps = kwargs.pop('laps', 2)  # default is to do 2 laps
        self.lap_counter = 0
        super(IncrediblyCrudeClock, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def start(self, *args):
        self.lap_counter += 1
        self.a = randint(3, 7)
        self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)
        if self.lap_counter >= self.max_laps:
            # this is the last lap, set on_complete to call self.finish_callback
            self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.finish_callback)
        else:
            # not finished yet, call self.start again
            self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.start)
        print('starting anim number', self.lap_counter)
        self.anim.start(self)

    def finish_callback(self, animation, incr_crude_clock):
        print('in finish_callback')
        self.text = 'FINISHED'

Builder.load_string('''
<IncrediblyCrudeClock>
    text: str(round(self.a, 1))
''')


class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # specify the number of repetitions in the constructor
        crudeclock = IncrediblyCrudeClock(laps=3)
        crudeclock.start()
        return crudeclock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```

Comment: That's excellent, thank you! would you mind just explaining to me what the pop() and super() methods in the __init__() function are doing please? My current understanding is that pop() can be used to remove a specific element from a list and super() is used to inherit from a parent class. It seems as though the pop function is setting max_laps as a key word argument, but I'm not sure how? Also, in this case is the super() method being used to set the arguments of the __init__ function as the arguments of the IncrediblyCrudeClock() class? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `kwargs` is a dictionary of key word arguments that are being passed into the `__init__()` method. The `pop` sets the value of `max_laps` to the value passed in (or to 2, if there is no `laps` key word provided). It also removes the `laps` key from the `kwargs` dictionary, so that the `__init__()` of `Label` will not encounter an unexpected key word. When you include your own `__init__()` in a subclass, it overrides the super class `__init__()`, and most classes must have their own `__init__()` executed in order to work correctly. The `super` calls the `__init__()` of the `Label`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your code, but here is a version of your `IncrediblyCrudeClock` that works:

```
class IncrediblyCrudeClock(Label):
    a = NumericProperty(0)  # Number of seconds to countdown

    def start(self):
        self.a = randint(3, 7)
        self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)
        self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.secondAnim)
        print('starting first anim')
        self.anim.start(self)

    def secondAnim(self, animation, incr_crude_clock):
        self.a = randint(3, 7)
        self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)
        self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.finish_callback)
        print('starting second anim')
        self.anim.start(self)

    def finish_callback(self, animation, incr_crude_clock):
        print('in finish_callback')
        self.text = 'FINISHED'
```

This is a very simple approach. I'm sure that the `start` and `secondAnim` methods could be combined as one method with a bit more logic.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Would you be able to give me some pointers on how you would combine the first and second method? I have used Spyder in the past and a process repeating a predetermined number of times would just require a simple for loop, but I can't work out how to implement that sort of approach here. I will eventually require the program to repeat a certain number of times specified by user input into a text input widget.